# mat-checkbox inside *ngFor is not working properly in material 6

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material-6

I am generating checkboxes inside an *ngFor using Angular 6 Material 6. The checkboxes are displayed properly. But when I click on any one of the checkboxes, they are flickering and not able to be checked properly.

I tried it in stackblitz, where it is working properly. I don't know if anything I have missed. I am struggling from past one week.

I have imported it properly in app.module.ts like this:

```
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
```

This is my code. Please suggest me any dependencies other than this I need to include.

```
<div *ngFor="let prop of reflectUI; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox>prop</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

i have used your code it's working properly and i added the below so go through these steps you have included or not may be it's helpful for you.

Step 1: app.module.ts

```
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

 imports: [MatCheckboxModule],
```

Step 2: styles.css

**import all below css files.**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import "~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
```

Step 3: Your code

```html
 <div *ngFor="let prop of reflectUI; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox>prop</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```